# How to save .mat file contents in memory in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, serialization, mat-file

I want to get the byte array of a .mat file of a specific matrix. How can I do that?

I can save a matrix on disk by this command:

```
save('a.mat', 'a')
```

Now, I do not want to save the .mat file on disk. Instead, I want it in memory to send it over a network.

Comment: do you mean `load('a.mat')`?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a couple of [undocumented functions](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/serializing-deserializing-matlab-data) (used internally by [`save`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) and [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html)) for serializing/deserializing data. This would allow you to encode your matrix `a` into a byte stream the same way `save` would when storing it in a .mat file:

```
byteStream = getByteStreamFromArray(a);
```

You can then send this byte stream data over a network and decode it on the receiving end like so:

```
a = getArrayFromByteStream(byteStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... if you want to send the binary content of a `mat` file through a network, you have no choice but proceeding as follows:

1. Save your data to disk in `mat` format:

   `save('a.mat','a');`
2. Read the saved `mat` file as a byte array:

   `fid = fopen('a.mat','r');`
   `data = fread(fid);`
3. Send the binary data through the network:

   `send_data(data);`

If you want to go for a much more elaborate approach (I don't recommend it by the way), like digging into a `mat` file in order to exctract data or building your own `mat` file at runtime, [this is a good starting point](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. But you could write the MAT file to a temporary directory (see `tempdir`) and then open it as a binary file, read its contents back in memory as a uint8 array or something like that.